# How to split long messages into short messages in gRPC C++

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, grpc

Context: I have a long message(~1G) to send over gRPC.(Why I use gRPC other than mere HTTP? 95% messages are shorter than 4MB)

Since gRPC default max send size is 4MB, I have to split them into multiple messages at server-side and reassemble them at client-side.

This is how I do:

1. Get the Response, and marshal it into a `std::string` by `response.SerializeToString(&str)`
2. Split the long string into multiple short strings, wrap them with a metadata(eg, index) and send them one by one
3. client-side receives all of them and concatenate them
4. Get Response by `message.ParseFromString(&concated_str)`

In these steps, I assume there're four times of copying 1GB data. Is there a way to avoid any of them, if possible?

Comment: For some context, we use protobuf with messages of a maximum size of 250 bytes. So from my point of view your average message size is still very large. Now that sad every application has it's own characteristics.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like OK.

But it is kind of rare to send such a huge message with rpc. Why don't you use some DB or messaging component such as Kafka or RabbitMQ? RPC is simply Remote Procedure Call, which means that you should use it just like calling a function. You can pass some arguments to a function but not a piece of 1G data. GRPC can retry and set timeout. You should set retry-times and timeout because you don't want to use the configuration by default. In your case, what if some retry happen while sending the third piece of data? This could happen because network is not always reliable. You ganna have to wait for a very long time to finish just one agent-level call. How would you set the timeout of GRPC? 10 seconds? 20 seconds? What if the first 1G request hasn't finished while the second one is coming? The stack may explode!

So your design may work as expected but is not a good design.

Do NOT try to use one technique to solve all of issues. GRPC is simply a kind of technique. But it's not a silver bullet. Sending huge data should use another technique. In fact, that's why people developed many kinds of messaging components.

I suggest you using a messaging queue, such as Kafka. 1G data can't be generated in one short, right? So when some data is generated, write them into Kafka immediately. And on the other side, read the Kafka queue.

Here is the architecture:

```
GRPC ----> Kafka writer ----> Kafka ----> Kafka reader ----> GRPC
```

You see that's why people invented a word: stream.

Do not regard 1G data as a piece of static data, instead, regard it as a stream.

Comment: Thanks for the sugguestion! I used gRPC as a streaming service, fetch data from storage side and transfer to client-side. Most data are pretty small, only ~0.5KB. But several super big.

Comment: @Dentiny Before coding, design. Before designing, analyze your needs. So you should first define what "several" is and what "big" is. GRPC with 1G data is not good. If I were you, I would use Kafka. Or, I would synchronize the storage of the caller of GRPC to the storage of the callee of GRPC (many DB support synchronization in a cluster now), which allows me to not use rpc at all and do job locally.

Comment: @Dentiny In a word, avoid using rpc with 1 GB data. That's it.

Comment: @Dentiny Or, write your 1GB data into a CDN, after that, send a simple GRPC request to notify the client to fetch data from the CDN. You see you have many choice. IMHO, rpc with 1G is not good.

Comment: I will seriously discuss with my manager. Thanks again for the suggestion!